# Is there any system specific content in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

Is there any content that is currently system specific in Destiny? As in only the Xbox or PS gets it.

This could make the difference of what platform I buy it on.

Comment: To weigh in on your decision as to which platform you should buy it on, you should definitely buy it on the platform you will have friends that will play it with you. Destiny is by far best when you're playing with friends, so if you have friends on Xbox that you would play with, I would pick that over the exclusive content. If you have friends on Playstation that will play with you, then you would get the best of both worlds, exclusive content and friends to play with.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I appreciate the advice. I mostly added the line after someone down voted without an explanation. I have friends to play with on both platforms

Comment: where your friends are is by far the biggest consideration, the PS exclusive things are a very small fraction of the total stuff in the game and not worth making a decision based on them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At launch, PS3 and PS4 will have some timed exclusive content:

- An exclusive strike mission
- An exclusive competitive map
- Exclusive weapons and other gear

All of this will become available on Xbox 360 and Xbox One autumn 2015.

[See this blog entry for more information](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2014/06/16/destinys-playstation-exclusive-content-detailed/), and [this IGN article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/09/04/discover-destinys-playstation-exclusive-dust-palace-mission) which mentions that Xbox owners will get it autumn 2015.